# Trying to connect via PowerShell to Azure with new AZ Module

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm desperate here with Powershell and Azure. 
I use PowerShell 7.0.1 and AZ 4.1.0.

When I try to connect (by the way, as global admin via 'Connect-AzAccount'), I get this prompt every time: `"WARNING: To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code xxxxxxxxx to authenticate."`
Of course I do that and then I get this error message every time:

```
Connect-AzAccount: xxxxxxxxxxxxx: Device authentication is required.
Trace ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Correlation ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Timestamp: 2020-05-20 09:12:18Z: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

Does anyone have an idea why this does not work? I have also tried it temporarily without MFA, with the same result.

Comment: Check this answer: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/9427#issuecomment-506087441

Answer (score 0):

As Allen pointed, the right thing to do in this case is to engage the ActiveDirectory authentication team.

> Meanwhile, can you try the preview of the new authentication experience [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Accounts/2.0.1-preview).
>   This uses a vastly updated authentication experience, and may unblock you while we work out the underlying issue.

Use the below script to install `Az.Accounts 2.0.1-preview` module.

```
Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -AllowPrerelease
```

For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/9427).

Answer (score 0):

I have installed `Az.Accounts 2.0.1-preview`, but now a different error message appears. After connecting all seams working fine, but after calling a function it comes to an error again:

```
PS> Connect-AzAccount -Subscription 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

WARNING: Attempting to launch a browser for authorization code login.
WARNING: We have launched a browser for you to login. For the old experience with device code flow, please run 'Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication'.
WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'

```
Account                        SubscriptionName TenantId                             Environment
-------                        ---------------- --------                             -----------
michael.kristen@inhouse.wko.at INH-Subscription xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx AzureCloud

PS> Get-AzDefault

Get-AzDefault: Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Connect-AzAccount to set up your Azure credentials.
```